# All Permutations of Multivariable Functions in Octave/Matlab

Tags: matlab, function, octave, permutation

I am trying to create a matrix of all possible permutations of a function from existing operators.
For example, if there were a function with two variables

```
f(x,y) with x = [1 2]; y=[1 2];
```

I want to make a matrix

```
[f(1,1),f(1,2);f(2,1),f(2,2)].
```

Would it be possible without using silly loops?
Ideally with an operation similar to `f([1:2],[1:2])`; which doesn't work.

If you know Haskell, I am looking for the same operation as

```
[f(x,y)|x<-[1,2],y<-[1,2]].
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`ndgrid`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) and then [`arrayfun`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html). But the latter is more or less the same as a loop:

```
[xx, yy] = ndgrid(x, y);
result = arrayfun(f, xx, yy)
```

To avoid loops or `arrayfun` you would need to defined the function `f` [*vectorized*](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html).